# A wired array's length is always 0 in angular2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I read `data.csv` file's content through browse, then I save part of this file's content to an array. I can use `console.log()` to print this array, but I always get `0` of this array's length.

Here is my code:

#### app.component.html

```
<form id="file-input-form" #fileInputForm>
  <h6>Sample Infomation</h6>
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file"
      (change)="onChange($event, 'sample_info', 'not_defined')"
      class="custom-file-input"
      accept=".csv"
      required>
      <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public sampleInfoStatus = [];
  public sampleNameInSampleInfo = [];

    onChange(event: EventTarget, type: string, pol: string): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext> event;
      let target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement> eventObj.target;
      let fileNum: number = target.files.length;
      let currentFile = target.files[0];
      let _sampleNames = [];
      let _sampleInfoStatus = [];
      let si_file = target.files[0];
      let read = new FileReader();
      read.readAsBinaryString(si_file);
      read.onloadend = function() {
        let sampleInfoRaw = read.result.replace(/\r\n?/g, '\n').split('\n');
        let sampleInfo = [];
        console.log(sampleInfoRaw);
        sampleInfoRaw = sampleInfoRaw.map((x) => x.split(','));
        sampleInfoRaw.forEach(ele => {
          ele = ele.map(x => x.replace(/^\"|\"$/g, ""));
          sampleInfo.push(ele);
        })
        let title = sampleInfo[0];
        console.log(title);
        if (title[0] !== 'sample.name') {
          _sampleInfoStatus.push(7);
        }
        if (title[1] !== 'group') {
          _sampleInfoStatus.push(8);
        }
        if (_sampleInfoStatus.length === 0) {
          sampleInfo.forEach(ele => {
            _sampleNames.push(ele[0]);
          });
        }
      }

      console.log(_sampleInfoStatus);
      console.log(typeof(_sampleInfoStatus));
      console.log(_sampleInfoStatus.length);
      console.log(_sampleNames);  // length is 12
      console.log(_sampleNames.length);  //<---- here is always zero
      console.log(_sampleNames.slice(0, 5));  //<---- always []
      console.log(_sampleNames);  // length is 12
      if (_sampleInfoStatus.length !== 0) {
        this.sampleInfoStatus = Object.assign([], _sampleInfoStatus);
        console.log(this.sampleInfoStatus);
      }
      if (_sampleNames.length !== 0) {
        console.log(_sampleNames);
        this.sampleNameInSampleInfo = Object.assign([], _sampleNames);
        console.log(this.sampleNameInSampleInfo);
      }

    }, 50)
  }
}
```

#### data.csv

```
sample.name,group
Sample12.QC12,QC
Sample1.QC11,QC
Sample23.QC13,QC
Sample34.QC14,QC
Sample45.QC15,QC
Sample56.QC16,QC
Sample67.QC17,QC
Sample78.QC18,QC
Sample10.P03.03,P03
Sample11.P03.06,P03
```

Here is online code that can run directly: https://angular-tm2a6q.stackblitz.io/

---

Finally, I wrote a service to read file:
All code can find here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hb81p7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: i use http service to read file data ...FileReader ?? i think there it is from other library ...

Comment: I can use it directly in angular.

Comment: Are you checking `length` outside `onloadend`? File reading is asynchronous, ie. whatever you are doing assuming file contents are loaded should be called from inside `onloadend`.

Comment: @sabithpocker You are right, that's my falut! But why can I print values by `console.log(_sampleNames);`

Comment: `_sampleNames` is a reference whose updated value may be printed by `console.log`. To get the exact value of the reference at that point of time logged you can try `console.log(JSON.stringify(_sampleNames))`.

Comment: I have corrected it, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tm2a6q?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts. I almost have started to doubt my life, because of this question!

Comment: Do we still have a question here? Also why do you have all those `setTimeout` in there?

Comment: Is there a better way to solve it without `setTimeout`?

Comment: You can write an answer below, I am not familiar with `js` and `angular`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159460/discussion-between-sabithpocker-and-belter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick fix for the issue, you should also look into `Observable.fromEvent` to handle such asynchronous cases in angular 2+

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public sampleInfoStatus = [];
  public sampleNameInSampleInfo = [];

  onChange(event: EventTarget, type: string, pol: string): void {
    let eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext>event;
    let target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>eventObj.target;
    let fileNum: number = target.files.length;
    let currentFile = target.files[0];
    let _sampleNames = [];
    let _sampleInfoStatus = [];
    let si_file = target.files[0];
    let read = new FileReader();
    read.readAsBinaryString(si_file);
    read.onloadend = () => {
      let sampleInfoRaw = read.result.replace(/\r\n?/g, '\n').split('\n');
      let sampleInfo = [];
      console.log(sampleInfoRaw);
      sampleInfoRaw = sampleInfoRaw.map((x) => x.split(','));
      sampleInfoRaw.forEach(ele => {
        ele = ele.map(x => x.replace(/^\"|\"$/g, ""));
        sampleInfo.push(ele);
      })
      let title = sampleInfo[0];
      console.log(title);
      if (title[0] !== 'sample.name') {
        _sampleInfoStatus.push(7);
      }
      if (title[1] !== 'group') {
        _sampleInfoStatus.push(8);
      }
      if (_sampleInfoStatus.length === 0) {
        sampleInfo.forEach(ele => {
          _sampleNames.push(ele[0]);
        });
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(_sampleInfoStatus));
      console.log(typeof (_sampleInfoStatus));
      console.log(_sampleInfoStatus.length);
      console.log(_sampleNames);  // length is 80
      console.log(_sampleNames.length);  // here is always zero
      console.log(_sampleNames.slice(0, 5));  // always []
      console.log(_sampleNames);  // length is 80
      if (_sampleInfoStatus.length !== 0) {
        this.sampleInfoStatus = Object.assign([], _sampleInfoStatus);
        console.log(this.sampleInfoStatus);
      }
      if (_sampleNames.length !== 0) {
        console.log(_sampleNames);
        this.sampleNameInSampleInfo = Object.assign([], _sampleNames);
        console.log(this.sampleNameInSampleInfo);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `console.log(_sampleNames.length);` outside of the `onloadend` event.

> The FileReader object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files

`onloadend` event is triggered each time the reading operation is completed (either in success or failure).

Before triggering onloadend event (before completing read operation), the remaining code will execute (here your `_sampleNames.length`). You will not get the expected result. All operations related to the _sampleNames array you have to do inside the onloadend event handler.